# failed to restore root filesystem from dump backup

Tags: backup, system-recovery, dump

I'm currently testing a backup/restore of RHEL 6.4 OS via the "dump" and "restore" on testing environment, and I do know that RHEL 6.4 seemed too outdated in nowadays. Butsome enterprises are still using such version of RHEL to load their services.

**Here's the scenario**: to backup the system and critical programs in case of host crash/failure event.

- The test RHEL 6.4 host for backup utilizes windows Hyper-V VM as infrastrucure and the OS root is installed on LVM logical volume.
- In order to backup the system, I placed system into single user mode and used command to backup the root filesystem

  ```shell
  dump -0uf /<path_to_a_second_storage_to_store_dump>/mybackup.dump /
  ```
- The dump showed "DUMP IS DONE" on screen and the dump file was created with size about 2.2GB therefore I believed that the backup was successful.

In order to simulate host crash event, I reinstalled the RHEL 6.4 system utilizing LVM logical volume and boot the system into single user mode before restoration.

However, after restoring root filesystem using

```shell
restore -rf /<path_to_a_second_storage_to_store_dump>/mybackup.dump
```

The screen showed kernel panic and some other errors, and hung eventually.

I retried several times but always failed.

Can anyone give me some hints why the restoration can't be completed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...

After tons of re-tries, I solved this root filesystem restore problem via using installation DVD's recue mode.

I discovered that the restoration of root filesystem from dump always conflicts with the running OS. Therefore, using rescue mode can handle it.

I'll make other try to see whether there's possibility to restore root filesystem when OS is running.